# "What/which actors do you admire most?"

Tags: word-usage

> 1. **Which** actors do you admire most?
> 2. **What** actors do you admire most?

Which of the two sentences sounds more natural to native speakers?

Answer (score 1):

Either one can be used.

A few websites I checked (like [this one](http://www.learnenglish.de/mistakes/whichvswhat.html)) recommended using *which* when there are a limited number of choices, and *what* when there are a seemingly unlimited number of choices.

So, it might be best to say:

> Which actor do you admire most – Brad Pitt or George Clooney?

but:

> What actors do you admire most?

if you want the person to be able to choose from any actor in all of cinematographic history.

But as for which sounds more natural, I'd need more context to say for sure.

As a footnote, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot) is a related ELU question.